# Exporting Symbol to DLL (via Module Definition File) Worked, But I Don't Know Why

Tags: c++, vba, dll, calling-convention, name-mangling

I was performing some experiments to learn the precise rules of module definition files, and I came across behavior I can't explain.  Here's the set-up:

NonMemberFunctions.h

```
#pragma once

extern "C" void __stdcall NonMemberTestFunction1();
void __stdcall NonMemberTestFunction2(void);
extern "C" void NonMemberTestFunction3(void);
```

NonMemberFunctions.cpp

```
#include <comutil.h>
#include "NonMemberFunctions.h"

extern "C" void __stdcall NonMemberTestFunction1()
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Non-Member Test Function1", L"hi", MB_OK);
}

void __stdcall NonMemberTestFunction2()
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Non-Member Test Function2", L"hi", MB_OK);
}

extern "C" void NonMemberTestFunction3()
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Non-Member Test Function3", L"hi", MB_OK);
}
```

exports.def

```
LIBRARY "Test1"
EXPORTS
    NonMemberTestFunction1
    NonMemberTestFunction2
    NonMemberTestFunction3
```

Excel VBA Module

```
Option Explicit

Public Declare Sub NonMemberTestFunction1 Lib "C:\foo\Test1.dll" ()
Public Declare Sub NonMemberTestFunction2 Lib "C:\foo\Test1.dll" ()
Public Declare Sub NonMemberTestFunction3 Lib "C:\foo\Test1.dll" ()

Sub Test1()
    Call NonMemberTestFunction1
    Call NonMemberTestFunction2
    Call NonMemberTestFunction3
    End  ' Release the DLL so I can recompile
End Sub
```

The surprising thing is that all `dll` calls worked.  I wasn't expecting that. The way I see the world, there are three hurdles:

1. Exportation of the symbol
2. The calling convention
3. Name mangling

Plopping all three symbols into the module definition file is enough to take care of #1.

For hurdle 2, I'm surprised call #3 worked because the C calling convention is `cdecl`, the VBA calling convention is `stdcall`, and the two (I thought) were incompatible.

For hurdle 3, I'm surprised call #2 worked because function #2 should've had its name mangled.  I think the reason for name mangling is to distinguish function signatures that differ only by argument, but this is true for non-member functions as it is for member functions.  How did this work?  I used `Dependency Walker` to look at the exported symbols in the `dll`, and sure enough, all three functions had their names intact:

```
??0CTest1@@QAE@XZ
??1CTest1@@QAE@XZ
??4CTest1@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z
?CTest1Public1@CTest1@@QAEXXZ
NonMemberTestFunction1
NonMemberTestFunction2
NonMemberTestFunction3
```

I understand why `NonMemberTestFunctions` 1 and 3 are not name mangled, but why isn't `NonMemberTestFunction2` not name mangled?  It should have C++ linkage.

Comment: Your functions don't take any parameters. There is no difference between __stdcall and __cdecl when there are no parameters. If you want to see it crash and burn, have them take at least one.

Comment: .DEF file suppresses name mangling. Functions are exported under the exact names as listed in the file. That's kind of the point.

Comment: Then it seems like module definition files are superior to the declspec mechanism for most uses.  It requires another project file, but not only does it suppress name mangling, but it also allows one to finely tune what gets exported from a class.  Declspec exports *all* member functions and static variables.

Are there any benefits to using the declspec mechanism?

Comment: `__declspec` is more convenient, for when you don't need any of that fine-tuning. And when you export class members, you actually need mangled names, which you would have to somehow discover before you can put them into the file (I doubt things like `??4CTest1@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z` just flow naturally from your fingertips).

Comment: Thanks.  "And when you export class members, you actually need mangled names" -- Why would someone need mangled names?  For the purpose of exporting overloaded functions?

Comment: How else would you name, say, a constructor? You can't just make up an arbitrary name - the linker wouldn't know which function it is supposed to go with. Roughly speaking, the name in the .DEF file must be "close enough" to the name the compiler hands to the linker.